# Random generate unique matrix

Tags: matlab

Could you help me. I want to generate matrix of '0' and '1' (for example rows 8 and columns 7; r and c). I want to specify fixed size columns (in this example fixed=3) and on it position in every execution should be all '0'. The rest should be randomly and unique selected. Here is example:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unique selected?"

Comment: Why not first generating a random matrix and then, in a second step, setting the elements you like to any value you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_matrix = [zeros(7, 3), floor(rand(7,4)*2)]
```

Comment: But in your code I can not specify number of columns?

Comment: @NikolaC of course you can, this is basic MATLAB indexing. Even without knowing MATLAB, given the fact that Matthew used the exact dimensions you proposed in your question, you should be able to figure out what to change for the number of columns.

Comment: You could of course use `round(rand(7,4))` instead of `floor`, both do the same thing in essencio

Comment: @Adriaan I tried but did not work